# How to load a single email to vb application?

Tags: vb.net, outlook

My Scenario,

I have outlook 2003, Now in my application til now i tried loading bulk of emails from folder to my application.But now i need to select a single email and load to application.How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way might be for the user to drag the desired email to the application.